# How do I re-enable incoming connections?

Tags: monerod, peer-discovery, peer

Over the course of several upgrades, I have been running `monerod` for many months now, and I have always connected to incoming peers.  For the last few months, it was always 8+37.

After running `git pull`, then backing up my wallet and keys file, then running `make clean`, and then `make`, now when I run `monerod`, my connections are always 8+0.  It's been like this for over 24 hours now.  Nothing changed with my router, so what might I need to do with my `monerod` config/settings to start accepting incoming connections?

If it helps to know, I run `monerod --rpc-bind-ip my.comp's.homenet.ip --confirm-external-bind` (which is the same as I've always run it, though I suppose the `--confirm-external-bind` wasn't needed before) on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, on version v0.10.2.1-1dfed89.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what my issue was.  I checked my `ufw` rules, and there was no rule for allowing port 18080.  After allowing that port and reopening `monerod` (not sure if that was necessary), I'm quickly up to 7+44.

(@TFI_Charmers, thanks for the push to double check the firewall.)

I don't know why ufw allowed it previously, with no rule, but it must have.  Nevertheless, it's good to know that it was not a monero issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was suffering from something similar yesterday. When I turned my OS X firewall off, I got the incoming connections back. When I turned it back on, I got 0 incoming connections again.

To fix it, I ended up forcing port 18080 open using [this guide](https://rolfje.wordpress.com/2014/05/10/open-a-port-in-osx-mavericks-firewall/). Scroll down to the 10th comment if you need help using Vim (I did). I turned the firewall back on and I got the incoming connections back.

Comment: I'm not on a Mac, so this doesn't exactly answer my question; but the firewall was the correct place to look.  Good stuff.

Comment: Ah...yes it reads like I was telling you how to open a port on a Mac. I was just putting it in there in case a Mac user had the same problem. However, I think I also have the same problem on my Lubuntu box so I need to apply your answer to that (I think). Cheers